# Haskell Parsec compile error

Tags: windows, haskell, parsec

I've installed Haskell via the pre built installer v6.8.2.

When trying to compile this sample file with GHC

```
module Main where
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec
import System.Environment

main :: IO ()
main = do args <- getArgs
          putStrLn ("Hello")
```

I get the following error:

```
D:\src\Haskell>ghc -o read read.hs
ghc -o read read.hs
read.o(.text+0x1b5):fake: undefined reference to   `__stginit_parseczm2zi1zi0zi0_TextziParserCombinatorsziParsec_'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have installed Parsec via cabal.

Does anyone have any idea's as to what is wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `ghc --make -o read read.hs`. GHC will take care of linker dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

I'll put out one other way to make this work

```
ghc -package parsec -o read read.hs
```

From the ghc documentation

```
-package P

This option causes the installed package P to be exposed. The package P can be 
specified in full with its version number (e.g. network-1.0) or the version number 
can be omitted if there is only one version of the package installed. If there are 
multiple versions of P installed, then all other versions will become hidden.

The -package P option also causes package P to be linked into the resulting 
executable or shared object. Whether a packages' library is linked statically or 
dynamically is controlled by the flag pair -static/-dynamic.
```

see http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/packages.html

Answer (score 1):

According to [the Parsec docs](http://legacy.cs.uu.nl/daan/download/parsec/parsec.pdf) (section 1.2.1 Compiling with GHC), you should do this:

> When your linking the files together,
>   you need to tell GHC where it can find
>   libraries (-L) and to link with the
>   Parsec library too (-l):
>     **`ghc -o myprogram myfile1.o myfile2.o -Lc:\parsec -lparsec`**

[This documentation](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.10-latest/html/users_guide/using-ghc.html) on the Haskell compiler may help.

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for but thank you anyway for trying;)